# Read JSON property in Java

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

I am getting below `output` when I am calling postAPI from `java`. I want to store `access_token` in a variable but I am not able to do it. in javascript I can do it easily but in Java it is becoming difficult for me. Can anybody help me on the same.

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IjZhYnBycWVsRl9ld3NEaW1HRy0wY0JpNVg2N09jQjkzTGNyN2Y4M3UzLXMiLCJ4NXQiOiJkdlhSRXBGdXpTenRMdGlMM2Vmbk1rbVo0Rk0iLCJraWQiOiJTSUdOSU5HX0tFWSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.X8wpGF9h018oWQrzOiTs1ST1rxSPzbAvH2xeFlfcO3vQwBjojsz9orCZZ5eqE834ot_UQc99xLA7JmeYMlv0i1Ud5uWcbP10gLaxKspmZFZFvDsCVTBSBYeG3yuthCUt2AyO1v1wSk25TTYOQfv-8rr8tErBq-it4p6vqNfoaLD91O3OWedl9FE1qbEq7RhIVKhpYryevGGnUJHBPL3FR3Jd7RbrVUPktj2KDLCUR85TauNn5nzEQzyvTlKIVPIUFANi2eD2JHRTcqA9kxRRUApY4qaVc-iqk_4mWrMuOPbS8TwPfZk97bWqov2Sg_KqRTlNffwRtVL9oUsLMMUjag",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with difficult to store the access_token in a variable? From what you wrote I would declare a String variable to hold the access_token. But I assume that there is more behind what you asked.

Comment: "I am not able to do it" is not a problem description: what have you _actually_ tried that doesn't seem to work? Because there are several libraries for parsing JSON in Java, and they're all extremely easily found with a single google search.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you Mike. I did try jackson but I was getting error. probably I was not including maven dependency. By the way why did you downvote the question?

Comment: @mohammedkhan Thank you Mohammed Khan. it helped to complete the requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   String data="{\"access_token\":\"eyJ4NXQjUzI1NiI6IjZhYnBycWVsRl9ld3NEaW1HRy0wY0JpNVg2N09jQjkzTGNyN2Y4M3UzLXMiLCJ4NXQiOiJkdlhSRXBGdXpTenRMdGlMM2Vmbk1rbVo0Rk0iLCJraWQiOiJTSUdOSU5HX0tFWSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.fFtCsQmgrf_jhU_pxa03O8ddP-1vjvOz7ciTqMbY-efeFsH1M17dzA2IAUlKbbg0I-bHHmu-IGBVTCaNwTuR5BaogR4z6ZlN03ojLkvbfstMlLxDqSn51U2v-wXXmF_Y7dypfxGqaDevlrlzJmh3Ve7Bq9AY0jMlwhLlMxLjvcVXGpGoiZ7a96K94rHUSgDf3-rZIy6dkYpTGWOaDV61Xfh3_HO8n85wUHVyqIuVjaeAg-BBModl2kd7oWp93bz9s_PA57d2Pr8yrbq7zxMbCSZ6fT_52_QJ17bAADBMvboXc0dDo1E6M1DgbQSnW80NDkYC_UI2OGFz-_Vg4aaPXw\",\"token_type\":\"Bearer\",\"expires_in\":3600}";
    //assign your JSON String here
   JsonObject obj=Json.parse(data).asObject();
   String accessToken=obj.get("access_token").asString();
     System.out.println(accessToken);
```